# What would be the architecturally-right place to put custom -D defines?

Tags: arduino-ide, build

What I am trying to accomplish is to include information about the state of my environment at build time in my code. For example, I may want the `setup()` code to print the git sha it was built against, and the time of build.

There are two related issues here:

1. How to include that information in the code
2. How to specify to the build environment what to generate in the first place.

The first can be addressed in a number of ways:

- -D options can be generated at build time, and the corresponding defined macros expanded in the code. For example, the compiler could be invoked as `g++ -DGIT_SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD) -DDATE=$(date '+%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S')`, and my code could have something like `#define strfy(_x) #_x` followed by `Serial.println(strfy(GIT_SHA));`. Or the build tool could generate a header file that would define these as external string variables, which the main sketch could then include and print. Or any other number of tricks.

The question I am really asking is: **how should I specify this sort of stuff for `arduino-builder`?**

Ideally, it would be a custom recipe in `platform.txt`, but if there is a way to invoke shell commands in recipes and use the results to modify other variables (such as `preproc.macro.flags`), I haven't been able to find it (if there is documentation, it's really well hidden). Ideally I would want to be able to say `preproc.macros.flags=-w -x c++ -E -CC -DGIT_SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD)` and have the shell command be executed at the point.

So, before I set out to hack arduino-builder, do people have any opinion on this? My main criterion is something that would be of general value and has a chance of being incorporated in the code, rather than a kludge that only works for me and which I have to patch every time I upgrade. Please do not suggest workarounds. I can think of several myself!

I *did* try to search, and this sort of issue has come up before, but I didn't see any satisfactory answers from people who knew what they were talking about.

Thanks!

/ji

Answer (score 1):

That is a tough one...  Because arduino-builder is basically a custom go script you don't get the facilities you get in a Makefile, like shell execution.

I would be inclined to do this kind of thing outside that environment - use some external program or tool to generate a config.h file (maybe use something like GNU Autotools) that contains your custom defines. That can then be #included in your sketch.

Answer (score 0):

For the date and time of compilation there are predefined preprocessor symbols: `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`.

Comment: Unfortunately these are at compile time and not at link time.

Comment: Seems appropriate; the OP used compiler command-string examples.

Comment: I'm not stating it is inappropriate. I'm adding that this solution has a drawback.  
From experience I learned that a IDE that only builds changed files (like the newest versions of the arduino IDE) will end up with outdated dates and time on the Arduino.